# Cookie jQuery очистка на всех страницах поддомена

Tags: jquery, cookie

Подскажите, как очистить значение `cookie` на всех страницах сайта по указанному ключу.

Пробывал вот так вообще нигде не очищает:

```
$.cookie('nsc_visID',null,{
    expires: 1,
    path: '/advertiser'
})
```

Вот так очищается только на страницах в корневой директории:

```
$.cookie('nsc_visID',null,{
    expires: 1,
    path: '/'
})
```

Comment: Проверил. Они не удаляются, просто значение затирается на `null`, ставьте expires 1 и они удалятся через сутки.

Answer (score 1):

```
function deleteAllCookies() {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");

    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = cookies[i];
        var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
        var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
        document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
    }
}
```